# Self Updating Powershell script

Tags: svn, powershell, powershell-2.0

What would be the best way to have a self updating (from SVN) Powershell script?

It should be able to start a new process and then call `SVN update $script; './$script'`, after making sure the current process has ended.

```
if ((svn st -u --quiet $script) -match "\*"){
     $scriptToRun = 'SVN update $script; "./$script"'
     ##start new process that will end this process and execute $scriptToRun
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this would do the trick, even if a little naive. You have two scripts - `StartApp.ps1` which does any necessary checks for updates. After running it then chains `MainApp.ps1` which is the app itself, this is what would get updated.

**StartApp.ps1** - kicks off app but also does the update check:

```
# Bootstrap app
#
# Check for updates here

if(some_check_to_determine_if_update_required)
{
    # Execute whatever external source control commands required but wait until 
    # done:
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "<path_to_svn>" -ArgumentList <args_you_need>
}

# Launch the (now possibly updated) app
.\MainApp.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's a good idea to have a script update itself. You might try doing it from the Task Scheduler or if the script must do it then break it into 2 parts the first one is what the user runs. Keep this small and simple. The second part is what you update out of svn and it should do the bulk of the work.

Basically small user script that handles arguments and autoupdate. Second part that does the bulk of the work and gets autoupdated.

Comment: I'm trying to make it self contained. I could make a master script that calls the main one, but then that one would need to be manually updated.

Comment: You might have your script call the "at" scheduler to do the update. It does one shot scheduling. Type "at /?" at a command prompt for help.

Answer (score 0):

1) Test if update is required. Stop if not needed.

2) Rename your executing script file.

3) Copy updated script to the original name

4) VERIFY copy. size, checksum, something. You still have a chance to recover here.

5) Execute the new script and exit running one.

You may have to figure out elevation if you need admin rights to overwrite the script. If you always run with elevated privileges, that shouldn't matter.